# Clean division of numbers

Tags: java

```
public class Evendiff 
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
    int x = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());

      if(x/y == 1)
      {
        System.out.print ( " true " ) ; 
         }
      else {
        System.out.print (" False "); 
      }

  }               
}
```

I just want it to take in two numbers as input , divide them and see if they divide up into each other cleanly (Like 5/5= 1 etc)
So, what am I doing wrong here? 
Also, I get the error java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Evendiff.main(Evendiff.java:6)
Never seen it before so I don't know anything about it.

Comment: What´s your `IDE`? `System#console` returns null for `eclipse` for example and hence would produce an error.

Comment: You have to use `x % y == 0`

Comment: I ran this code using command-prompt and it's working perfectly fine. I think it's an `IDE` problem.

Comment: What's the problem? What result are you expecting? What result are you getting?

Comment: And the error it also pops up is this: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Evendiff.main(Evendiff.java:6)
>

Comment: Please edit your question with those details.

Comment: "Never seen it before so I don't know anything about it."
It's like there were no 1000s questions about NullPointerException before.

Answer (score 3):

> see if they divide up into each other cleanly

If by that you mean that the first number is divisible by the second number, you should be using the modulus operator `%`, not the division operator `/` (i.e. you should be checking whether the remainder `x % y` is `0`).

`x/y` would return 1 if `x >= y` and `x < 2 * y`. I don't think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks man!! that really did help.
But if I can also ask you, java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Evendiff.main(Evendiff.java:6)
why would the IDE poop out that error?

Comment: @Josef `System.console()` will return null depending on the IDE you use, DrJava being an example. Best to use `Scanner` instead.